# Valores padrões no model - Django

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

Estou estudando django e tentando definir um valor padrão para um campo, quando `makemigrations` é executado, informaria que tal campo receberia uma valor padrão como **0**

```
models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Acontece que *Predefinido* fica definido como *None*

Não estou entendo, a documentação diz tudo menos o que eu quero.

```
models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

O predefinido ficar com o valor 0 também.

Meu model:

```
class User(models.Model):
  # User fields for login
  username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  gender   = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  status   = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  premium  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  ip       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Onde `default=0` seria o valor padrão para o campo

Comment: Mostra a sua definição dos models envolvidos, explica melhor o que esta acontecendo que vc nao gostaria que acontecesse, qual é a msg de warging ou erro se houver.

Comment: @Sidon editei o post

Comment: Mas nao explicou o "problema", alguma msg de erro? em tempo: User já é um model do django, vc pode extende-lo mas não da forma como vc esta fazendo.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando uma tabela diferente do User, não existe nada errado com o teu código, o que falta é correr um comando, tens de correr, por esta ordem:

- python manage.py makemigrations
- python manage.py migrate